# File.createTempFile check if file exists?

Tags: java

If I use this method, and by chance there is a temporary file with the same name, the file is overwritten? 
I'm talking about an application that will generate many temporary files, for a long time.

Comment: how about showing some code..

Comment: Why not check first if there is already a file with the same name with exists()? That way you can control what is the best approach in that situation.

Comment: Because I would have to create a loop and an unnecessary overhead. Something like: `while(file.exists()) getNextName()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the JavaDoc on `createTempFile` ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29)) on the line  labeled `2`,

> Neither this method nor any of its variants will return the same abstract pathname again in the current invocation of the virtual machine.

**Edit**

And the **Returns** section says

> An abstract pathname denoting a newly-created empty file

And, it further states

> Creates a new empty file in the specified directory, using the given prefix and suffix strings to generate its name. If this method returns successfully then it is **guaranteed** that: The file denoted by the returned abstract pathname **did not exist before this method was invoked**

Comment: this doesn't mention if it checks if the file exists or not... However, the link you've given also tells that "Creates a new empty file in the specified directory, using the given prefix and suffix strings to generate its name. If this method returns successfully then it is **guaranteed** that: The file denoted by the returned abstract pathname **did not exist before this method was invoked**"

Comment: Thanks! It's enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use a counter to create a new file name, if one already exists like this

```
File file = new File(filename);
for (int i = 0; file.exists(); i++) {
    file = new File(filename + i);
}
// write the file now
```

Hope it gives an idea!

Comment: It does not work. The file creation occurs within several different threads. Thanks.

Comment: ok, You have make the method synchronized and keep the counter (`i`) as `static`

Comment: I have the problem of variable be reset with each new deployment.